# Изменить скрипт добавления корзину

Tags: javascript

Я нашел скрипт корзины написанный исключительно на JS, вот он

https://codepen.io/chrisachinga/pen/MWwrZLJ

Мне необходимо чтобы при добавлении товара в корзину количество товара бралось из data аттрибута, скажем data-count. Сейчас при добавлении товара всегда добавляется одна позиция.

Пытался в событии AddItem менять количество, но оно срабатывает только единожды(если товар не добавлялся ранее):

```
// Add item
$('.add-to-cart').click(function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
var name = $(this).data('name');
var price = Number($(this).data('price'));
var count = Number($(this).data('count'));
shoppingCart.addItemToCart(name, price, count);
displayCart();
```

Буду признателен за подсказку или помощью.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно внести изменение в методе `addItemToCart`:

```
  // Add to cart
  obj.addItemToCart = function(name, price, count) {
    for(var item in cart) {
      if(cart[item].name === name) { //Если товар в корзине
        //cart[item].count ++; //Убираем инкремент на 1
        cart[item].count += count;//Добавляем количество
        saveCart();
        return;
      }
    }
    var item = new Item(name, price, count);
    cart.push(item);
    saveCart();
  }

// +1
$('.show-cart').on("click", ".plus-item", function(event) {
  var name = $(this).data('name')
  //shoppingCart.addItemToCart(name);
  shoppingCart.addItemToCart(name, null, 1);
  displayCart();
})
```